# Check if checkbox is checked using next() in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if a `checkbox` next to a `textbox` is checked or not, but the result I'm getting from that condition in my code is always true, so that's wrong.

I've made some tests using the `next()` method from jQuery. I'm pointing to the next `checkbox` close to the `textbox`, which is working fine.

This code is always returning true, whether the `checkbox` is checked or not:

```
if ($(this).next('.isFileSelected:checkbox:checked')) {
    //do some other stuff...
}
```

I tried these changes too, but I'm getting the same results:

```
if ($(this).next('input:checkbox:checked')) {
    //do some other stuff...
}
```

How can I accomplish this using jQuery or pure JavaScript code?

Comment: jquery filtering methods always return jquery collections. jquery collections are always objects, and therefore are always true.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks, what worked for me was this : `if ($(this).next().is(':checked')) { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the **[prop()](https://api.jquery.com/prop)** attribute `checked`:

```
if ($(this).next('.isFileSelected:checkbox').prop('checked')) {
  // Checked
}
```

Or, alternatively, you can use **[.is()](https://api.jquery.com/is/)** to check for the `:checked` pseudo-selector:

```
 if ($(this).next('.isFileSelected:checkbox').is(":checked")) {
  // Also Checked
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Beat me too it! GJ on the quick answer

Comment: yeap it did help, actually what worked for me was this approach: `if ($(this).next().is(':checked'))` . I'm not sure why it didn't work using prop().. thank you :) !!

Comment: `.is(':checked')` is what I would use too, but in the first example, shouldn't it be `.prop('checked')`, since `.prop('checked', true)` would set the checked property to true and return the jQuery object (which is not a falsy value, making the if statement evaluate to true)?

Comment: @mark.hch -- You are correct; `.prop('checked', true)` **sets** the value to `true`, while `.prop('checked')` checks if it **is** true. I've updated the answer to fix that :)